# Dualboot (Win7 & Ubuntu) on SSD

Tags: partitioning, windows, ssd

Advice please. Can I install Windows 7 (Windows 8) and Ubuntu on an SSD with the ability to dualboot? And if so, how best to partition the disk?

SSD - VTX3-25SAT3-60G

For example:
1. Windows - 25Gb
2. Linux - 25Gb
2.1 /boot - 300Mb
2.2 / - 20Gb
2.3 /swap - 2.7Gb (16Gb RAM, just in case)

And as in this case, it is best to align the sections?

Answer (score 2):

You can dual-boot or triple-boot from an SSD just like from HDD, there's absolutely no difference, it will be just faster.

Partition alignment is very important for SSDs because of their large physical block size. Ubuntu installer aligns partitions optimally by default. So does GParted.

Regarding your partitioning scheme - I see no sense in separate `/boot` partition, but otherwise it would work just like any other.